# Kubernetes on AWS ELB names

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

When running Kubernetes on AWS, exposing a Service with "type=LoadBalancer" works well. However, the name given to the Elastic Load Balancer is a rather long hash and as such, it is hard to keep track through the AWS console as to which load balancer belongs to which Service.

Is it possible to specify he name of the ELB object at service creation time?

If not, I might create an issue that the service name be used when creating the ELB.

On a related note, is it possible to modify the security group (firewall) that the load balancer uses?

Answer (score 0):

The tags of the ELB contain the information you're looking for.

```
$ aws elb describe-tags --load-balancer-names xxxxx
{
    "TagDescriptions": [
        {
            "LoadBalancerName": "xxxxx",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "default/nginx",
                    "Key": "kubernetes.io/service-name"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "my-cluster",
                    "Key": "KubernetesCluster"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to give the ELB a proper domain name, you can assign one using Route53. It can be automated with something like [route53-kubernetes](https://github.com/wearemolecule/route53-kubernetes).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I will definitely make use of that tool to setup DNS. Regarding the ELB name question, I know I can change it after it's created, I was more asking whether I could change the name used at ELB creation time.

Comment: You don't have to change anything to get the tags. Those are automatic. I don't think there is a way to change the name from k8s. It seems to take the UID of the service as the name.